# an element with the same SQL SERVER key has already been added

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Good morning community, I am having problems when I run this query from SQL 2018 and Visual basic 2010 shows me the following error **"an element with the same key has already been added"**

```
SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'DEPA' + CAST(IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,''AS nodeParentKey FROM DEPARTAMENTO
UNION ALL
SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'PROV' + CAST(IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,
'DEPA' + CAST(IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey FROM PROVINCIA
UNION ALL
SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'DIST' + CAST(IDUBIGEO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,
'PROV' + CAST(IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey FROM ubigeo
```

**As I can avoid duplicate elements, I think it is with the DISTINCT clause but I have no idea where this clause can go, please support**

Comment: `an element with the same key has already been added` is not a SQL Server error message.  It's coming from VB.NET.

Comment: the message comes from visual basic, what happens is that the same code I run for another database works perfect, but with this database with the records already complete it shows me this message

Comment: Well what data is returned by the query and how are you adding it to a Dictionary in VB?

Comment: post the answer, lines below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use UNION instead of UNION ALL in this way:

```
SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'DEPA' + CAST(IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS 
nodeKey,''AS nodeParentKey FROM DEPARTAMENTO
UNION ALL
SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'PROV' + CAST(IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,
'DEPA' + CAST(IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey FROM PROVINCIA
UNION
SELECT DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,'DIST' + CAST(IDUBIGEO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,
'PROV' + CAST(IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey FROM ubigeo
```

it will remove duplicates

Comment: change what it indicates but this error still appears, if this query eliminates the duplicates then I think the one that is failing is visual, I will not continue testing it yet.